# packaging an uncooked/raw hot sauce

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, canning

I make a hot sauce with peppers,parsley,garlic,salt and olive oil. I have to freeze it in jars otherwise it ferments. Is there a way to package a raw/ uncooked product without fermentation?

Comment: *You don't want* to if garlic and olive oil are involved, see [this post](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9451/botulism-garlic-cold-pressed-olive-oil-and-mason-jars) for example. Welcome to the site!

Comment: depends on what you consider uncooked?  Boiling for 10-15 mins in can would work and keep your food safe.  

Otherwise you need to use chemicals or PH to kill off the yeast and other hungry guys that want to eat the sugars.

Answer (score 1):

Without the olive oil it would probably be okay to pressure can (although without knowing the full recipe I can't give any processing details).
In canning though some spices go a bit funny and can change in taste so that would be something to watch out for.

The biggest thing though is that canning is NOT appropriate for this sauce because of the olive oil. High fat and oily products are not safe to can despite what may be seen on youtube/pintrest. The oil affects the heat penetration and there is no guaranteed way to know when the heat has fully penetrated. Furthermore, grease coats the botulism spores and protects them from heat. Botulism toxin (produced by spores that have not been "killed") are the main (deadly) health concern with improperly processed canned goods.

I would advise freezing. Possibly it may work to add a number of preservatives to it but... that would probably change the taste quite a lot.

Comment: In other words, (1) you can't do this safely, and (2) even if you could, you'd have to properly pressure can it, so it wouldn't actually be raw anymore.