# Greece salad dressing stay good in the fridge?

Tags: salad-dressing

How long will homemade Greece salad dressing stay good in the fridge? with garlic, extra olive oil, sea salt, lemon juice, oregano dried and basil dry and wine vinegar.. if I made like 2 liters for that to use avg 2-3 times a week

thanks

Kelly

Comment: I just used some vinaigrette tonight that I had in the fridge for quite some time (a few weeks, I think) -- but I had no garlic in it, which [can be a botulism risk](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/19581/67). The problem was that it's generally okay as-is for a day or two, but after a while, the olive oil partially solidifies.  (I microwaved it for a few seconds, as I had it in a glass jar.)  ... and before someone complains about me answering the question in a comment -- no I didn't.  I have no answer, just possible problems.