# Homemade fresh garlic dressing fridge life

Tags: garlic

In my dressing I use fresh pressed garlic cloves, apple cider vinegar,  extra virgin olive oil , salt & pepper in a quart jar. How long can I store this safely in the fridge? There is absolutely **no mayonnaise**.

Comment: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9451/botulism-garlic-cold-pressed-olive-oil-and-mason-jars, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15553/how-long-will-homemade-salad-dressing-stay-good-in-the-fridge, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12761/garlic-infused-oilsafety - it is not about the mayonnaise, don't keep it longer than 3-4 days. For general reference, also use http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer (does not cover homemade dressing yet, but maybe will) and stilltasty.com.

Answer (score 1):

Really it is dependent on the acidity of the mixture. For example if you were pickling the garlic you could have a shelf life of several months. However using olive oil changes the acidity lowering the shelf life. If I remember correctly, at the last restaurant I worked at we only kept our house made vinaigrette for 7 days.

On a side note, keeping your mixture in the fridge is extremely important in order to avoid botulism which is found in soil and on the surfaces of certain produce.

Answer (score -3):

I would say a couple of weeks but check to make sure after 8 days because of the garlic. Garlic can go bad real fast sometimes.

Comment: *C. botulinum* is invisible and tasteless. No way of knowing if the mixture is bad.