# Botulism in regards to microwaving garlic, honey, ACV, lemon juice, olive oil and powdered ginger for 15 seconds

Tags: botulism

I am wondering if I mix 1 tbs of honey, ACV and olive oil with 1 crushed garlic with a squirt of lemon juice, then microwave it for 15 seconds (enough make the mixture bubble but not overflow) can that cause botulism if I immediately drink the mixture afterwards?

Comment: What is ‘acv’? If it's an acronym (e.g. for apple cider vinegar?), then capitalising it would make that clearer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make garlic oil in a safe way...tomorrow](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15113/how-to-make-garlic-oil-in-a-safe-way-tomorrow)

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Questions about garlic, oil, and botulism have been asked multiple times, and I think you'll find that the answers to those cover what you need to know.  That includes these questions: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/39432/7180  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/15113/7180

Comment: No, but why would you do that? The mix seems very strange to me. What is this for?

Comment: Neinstein: from the ingredients, sounds like Greek ladelomomo dressing.

Comment: Just to note, you mentioned powdered ginger in the title but not in the body of the question. You can [edit] if you need to fix that.

Answer (score 37):

No, of course not. Botulism is the result of bacterial fermentation over a long period of time. If the ingredients are safe, mixing them will also be safe.

Comment: I would suggest adding the corollary that if the ingredients were *not* safe in the first place, then microwaving them will not "kill the spores".

Comment: @FedericoPoloni That's not what the OP was asking about. None of the OP's ingredients are "suspect". (FWIW, though, boiling for long enough *will* inactivate botulinum toxin, which is all that matters for eating it.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The spores are not dangerous to >6 months olds, or we would all be dead by now. *Bacteria and viruses*, on the other hand, will suffer a lot from 15 seconds of boiling (if I understand the OP right). It's basically a flash pasteurization that just falls a bit short of industry standards.

Comment: Thanks @Sneftel and Peter for the corrections; this seems useful information.

Comment: Might want to clarify "a long period of time".  Botulism can poison a mixture in as little as 72 hours.  Much more than the OP is asking about, but folks may refer to your answer out of context.

Comment: @Sneftel Honey and garlic absolutely can contain C botulinum. It just is usually not harmful to adults.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I've heard/read that you should avoid using fresh garlic in sous vide recipes because of the risk of botulin poisoning.  But the time in question doesn't seem to be of concern.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The *toxin* is destroyed by heat but the spores are heat resistant and the spores will turn into more C. botulinum over time in oil. That's why it's important to make the distinction that it's safe to consume immediately but storage is more difficult (microwaving does not make it safe to store).