# Best lid for glass jar of chutney contains raw garlic, herbs, hot pepper, all in apple vinegar

Tags: lid

I intend to make a lot of chutney with raw garlic, herbs, green small hot pepper, salt, pepper, turmeric, all in apple vinegar. I want to store this chutney out of fridge, in glass jars for long time. I think mixture of apple vinegar, salt and hot pepper will keep the garlic and herbs preserved for months and not go bad, but I heard that any metal lid will rot in touch with vinegar. I also don't like plastic lid. Any suggestion?

Comment: I've never seen a jar of pickles without a metal lid, so I'm not sure where you got the idea that metal cannot be used with acidity.

Comment: The pickles has %5 vinegar and acidity but I will use %100 vinegar, no water add. My friend who make something similar with %100 vinegar told me the lid on Mason jars always corrode and rust .

Comment: See [this post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/120243/botulism-in-regards-to-microwaving-garlic-honey-acv-lemon-juice-olive-oi) for in-depth information about preparing garlic to prevent botulism.

Comment: standard vinegar is 5% acidity, are you making your own vinegar?

Comment: Your vinegar is not 100% acidity.  That would meant that you're just adding pure acetic acid -- which is not vinegar.

Comment: what I meant was to make pickle they add the vegetable to mixture of vinegar and water but for what I make there is no water add and its 100% vinegar. Then its stronger acidity than pickles.

Comment: I intend to make small business and sell my product. I need something to be safe and not expensive.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider Weck canning jars.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are plastic lids available for standard canning jar sizes, both as sealing disk only (for use with metal screw bands and rubber gaskets), and as a combined top and screw band.

Comment: The OP writes: “ I also don't like plastic lid”.