# Botulism Olives, Olive Oil and garlic

Tags: botulism

I have been doing olives (mixed kalamata and jumbo green/mazinilla) with a salty brine with dehydrated galic and herbs with a layer of olive oil over the top.  Now is this safe or not?? i leave it to stand to draw the flavours and usually at room temp.

Comment: Because this specifically asks about *dehydrated* garlic (not fresh) it's a little bit closer to this one: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/dry-garlic-in-oil-botulism-risk

Comment: @logophobe: I also thought about this but OP also mentions olives which are not dehydrated.

Comment: I don't think olives are typically a botulism risk because of the curing process, but no matter. The point is that we've got several versions of this question floating around.

Comment: This one also has a bunch of brine in it...